# Add custom url to featured image

Tags: php, images

Good afternoon everyone, I have little experience in php programming and I have a problem with the featured images.
Use Advanced Custom Field’s and create a field where i put a URL. Need when click in the featured image this take the URL of ACF and open in new tab. I found this code where the featured image call the link, but i need to put my custom URL.

```
    if ( $args['apply_link'] ) {
    $out_escaped .= '<a class="g1-frame" href="' . esc_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post ), $post ) ) . '">';
    $out_escaped .= '<span class="g1-frame-inner"' . $inner_style_escaped . '>';

    if ( $args['use_microdata'] ) {
        $out_escaped .= get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $args['size'], array( 'itemprop' => 'contentUrl' ) );
    } else {
        $out_escaped .= get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $args['size'] );
    }

    $out_escaped .= '<span class="g1-frame-icon"></span>';
```

I dont know how to call my custom URL to add in featured image.
The code of ACF is ?php the_field('custom_url'); ?>

Some idea to work properly?

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this pretty simply. I'm guessing you are inside the wordpress loop. Basically, get the link url, get the image url, echo out.

```
<?php 
  $custom_link = the_field('custom_url'); //probably want to check if this is empty
  $post_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id );//you can pass size if you would like
  echo '<a href="' . $custom_link . ' target="_blank"><img src="' . $post_thumb . '/></a>';
?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/